# VPN client to client port forwarding

Tags: vpn, openvpn, pptp, pptpd

I have an EC2 Amazon instance running a vpn server with 192.168.240.1-9 ip range.

I can connect my Macbook to this VPN (using system pref.) and a Raspberry Pi, using this command line:

> sudo pptpsetup --create vpnec2 --server ip_to_my_EC2 --username myUser --password myPassword --encrypt —start

My Rasperry Pi is running a few Python apps (sickeard, transmission, etc...) on separate ports.

```
**EC2** VPN ip: 192.168.240.1

**RasPi**: 192.168.240.2

**Macbook**: 192.168.240.3
```

From both computers, I can ping the server. From the server, I can ping the computers. I can also browse sickbeard, transmission, using **Lynx** from the server. But I can't ping client-to-client, there is no response.

My goal is to be able to browse the applications from my Macbook, using for example

```
http://192.168.240.2:9091
```

On the EC2 instance, **ipv4.ip_forward=1** is uncommented.

How can I forward the ports I need between the computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to setup a route for the network via the EC2 instance on your client machines. Something along

```
ip r add $VPN-net via $Peer dev $VPN-device
```

e.g.

```
ip r add 192.168.240.0/28 via 192.168.240.1 dev ppp0
```